# Change the order of literal in code snippet

Tags: c#, xml, code-snippets

I have generated a code snippet for a simple function

The `function` is:-

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Description
    /// </summary>
    public static int function(int obj)
    {
        return obj;
    }
```

And the `Snippet` for the code is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword>fpub</Keyword>
      </Keywords>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>fpub</Title>
      <Author>shaveta.drake@hotmail.com</Author>
      <Description>Generate public method</Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>fpub</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>function</ID>
          <ToolTip>Name of Function</ToolTip>
          <Default>function</Default>
          <Function>First Argument</Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>obj</ID>
          <ToolTip>obj</ToolTip>
          <Default>obj</Default>
          <Function>Second Argument</Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>int</ID>
          <ToolTip>Datatype</ToolTip>
          <Default>int</Default>
          <Function>Third Argument</Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>Description</ID>
          <ToolTip>Description</ToolTip>
          <Default>Description</Default>
          <Function>Fourth Argument</Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[/// <summary>
/// $Description$
/// </summary>
public static $int$ $function$($int$ $obj$)
{
    return $obj$;
}]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

When i implement the `snippet`,

the default order starts with **Desciprion**,

whereas i want to start with **function**

so is there any way i could **manage the order of the literals**.

Comment: AFAIK it takes them in order of appearance, but I might be wrong =/

Comment: could you provide a simple implementation?

Comment: Downvoters Please be kind enough to drop a explanation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having had a look through [the MSDN documentation for code-snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) I have come to the conclusion that the appearance of the objects / literals in the `<Code>` element is what decides the order when you are using the snippet. Which means that you cannot change the order as far as I know.

Comment: OK, i think you're right ..
so there is no other possibility??

Comment: Not as far as I know I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I need to create code snippet for complex property where the order of literals are very important for user. I create the comment line above the generated code, where the literals are used in required order.

Important part

```
...
<Code Language="csharp">
    <![CDATA[
        // Cfg: $type$ $configname$ def: $defaultvalue$ desc: $description$ cat: $category$ resName: LocDesc_$configname$
        /// <summary>
        /// $description$
        /// </summary>
        [LocalizedCategory("$category$", "LocCat_$category$")]
        [DefaultValue($defaultvalue$)]
        [LocalizedDescription("$description$", "LocDesc_$configname$")]
        public $type$ $configname$
        {
...
```

Full snippet

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Localized config item</Title>
            <Shortcut>lcfg</Shortcut>
            <Description>
                Code snippet for an automatically implemented property in Configuration class
            </Description>
            <Author>Arkance Development</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>configname</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>defaultvalue</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Default property value</ToolTip>
                    <Default>DefaultValue</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>description</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property description</ToolTip>
                    <Default>description</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>category</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property category</ToolTip>
                    <Default>General</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp">
                <![CDATA[
        // Cfg: $type$ $configname$ def: $defaultvalue$ desc: $description$ cat: $category$ resName: LocDesc_$configname$
        /// <summary>
        /// $description$
        /// </summary>
        [LocalizedCategory("$category$", "LocCat_$category$")]
        [DefaultValue($defaultvalue$)]
        [LocalizedDescription("$description$", "LocDesc_$configname$")]
        public $type$ $configname$
        {
            [DebuggerStepThrough()]
            get
            {
                string settingName = "$configname$";
                $type$ defaultValue = $defaultvalue$;
                $type$ retVal = GetSetting(settingName, defaultValue);
                return retVal;
            }
            [DebuggerStepThrough()]
            set
            {
                string settingName = "$configname$";
                SetSetting(settingName, value);
            }
        }
        
        $end$
        ]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```